# Lanczos algorithm for finding top eigenvalues of a matrix sum

Tags: linear-algebra, python, eigenvalues, scipy, numpy

I am trying to find the top `k` leading eigenvalues of a NumPy matrix (using python dot product notation) `L@L + a*X@X.T`, where $L$ and $X$ are a symmetric $n \times n$ and an $n \times d$ matrix, respectively, and $a$ is a scalar.

According to the below text from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2158) paper, I should be able to calculate these leading eigenvalues with `L@(L@v) + a*X@(X.T@v)`, where I guess `v` is an arbitrary vector. The Lanczos paper they cite is [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-006-9057-z).

I'm not quite sure where to start. I know that scipy has `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html), and from the notes it looks like it uses the Lanczos algorithm - but I am at a loss as to whether it's possible to use `sparse.linalg.eigsh` for my specific use case. I googled around and didn't find a Python implementation for this very quickly -- does anybody know if I can use `sparse.linalg.eigsh` to calculate this somehow? I definitely don't want to write this algorithm out myself if I can avoid it.

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a [linear opearator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator)
and pass it to the function `eigsh`. Ideally, your matrices $L$ and $X$ are sparse so you
can take advantage of the matrix-vector product.

In your case, you would have something like the following.

````py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator, eigsh

def mv(v):
    a = 2.3
    return L@(L@v) + a*X@(X.T@v)

n = L.shape[0]
k = 10
A = LinearOperator((n, n), matvec=mv)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = eigsh(A, k=k, which="LM")
```
````

Comment: I'll play around with this, thank you so much!